# How can make a custom extension for Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, extension-methods

I am trying to add a function to Dictionary, this func called add, which has 2 input values (key and value). I tried to make the func be generic, that means I want key and value be able take any Type. I end it up to this down non-working code. What I should do next to make this func work?

```
extension Dictionary {
    func add<Key, Value>(key: Key, value: Value) {
        self[Key] = Value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are trying to assign a type instead of an instance to the dictionary.

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context):

---

Second, you need to declare your method as mutating.

> Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only).

---

Third, you are creating two new generic types that have no relation with the Dictionary generic Key and Value types.

> Cannot convert value of type 'Key' (generic parameter of instance method 'add(key:value:)') to expected argument type 'Key' (generic parameter of generic struct 'Dictionary').

---

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func add(key: Key, value: Value) {
        self[key] = value
    }
}
```

---

```
var dict: [String: Int] = [:]
dict.add(key: "One", value: 1)
dict  // ["One": 1]
```

Comment: I didn't know that three asterisks would put a dash in your post. I'll have to remember that. (Oh yeah, and great answer, as usual. Voted.)